# How to copy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

It seems like a simple question. But for me it is tricky... Sorry.
I have a big ndarray with shape (2800, 256, 256, 3) which was filled with zeros.
And I have a ndarray with shape (700, 256, 256, 3) with data. So I want copy data to the first array. In such way that only first 700 rows in the first array will be with data from the second array. So how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: No! I want that initial array will be with shape 2800, not 700.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690248/copy-numpy-array-into-part-of-another-array

Answer (score 1):

You copy an array into a slice of another array with sliced indexing:

```
In [41]: arr = np.zeros((4,3,2), int)
In [42]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)
In [43]: arr[:2,:,:] = x
In [44]: arr
Out[44]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

`arr[:2] = x` works just as well, but sometimes it helps us humans to see what dimensions are being copied.

It doesn't have to be a slice, as long as the `=` immediately follows.

```
In [46]: arr[[0,2],:,:] = x
In [47]: arr
Out[47]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do:

```
arr2 = arr1[:700,:,:,:].copy()
```

This slices the array along the first axis up to index 700, (which gives you the first 700 entries), and copies all of the other axes of those rows.

Comment: To make a copy rather than a view you need `arr2 = arr1[:700,:,:,:].copy()`

Comment: I believe it should be the other way round.

Comment: No! I dont want dimensions in the first array. After your descision it will have shape (700, 256, 256, 3). But I want (2800, 256, 256, 3) where only first 700 rows contains data.  @LizardCode

Comment: Then you just want `arr[:700,...] = arr2` don't you?

Comment: @xnx It is not working. There are still zeros in the first array.

Comment: Zeros in the first 700 rows? Are you sure they weren't in the second array you copied in?