# Efficiently imprint an array onto another in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a function that imprints a smaller array onto another. The dimensions and center are arbitrary. For example I may want to put a 3x3 on a 5x5 at center (1, 2) or I may want to put a 5x5 on a 100x100 at center (50, 30). Ignoring indexing errors and even arrays that have no center.

```
Example:
arr1 = 
[2, 3, 5]
[1, 5, 6]
[1, 0, 1]

arr2 = 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

arr3 = imprintarray(arr1, arr2, (1, 2))

arr3 =
[0, 2, 3, 5, 0]
[0, 1, 5, 6, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I call the first array the smallarray (the one that is imprinted) and the second array to be the map array (the bigger array who has its values modified)

My solution was to create a 3rd array with the target indexes on the the maparray and to iterate through accessing the smallarrays values and changing the elements of the maparray directly.

```
import numpy as np

maparray = np.zeros((9, 9))
smallarray = np.zeros((3, 3))
smallarray[:] = 2


def createindexarray(dimensions, center):
    array = []
    adjustment = (dimensions[0] * -0.5) + 0.5
    for row in range(dimensions[0]):
        elements = []
        for col in range(dimensions[1]):
            elements.append((row + center[0] + int(adjustment), col + center[1] + int(adjustment)))
        array.append(elements)
    return array


indexarray = createindexarray((3, 3), (3, 5))

for w, x in enumerate(smallarray):
    for y, z in enumerate(x):
        maparray[indexarray[w][y][0]][indexarray[w][y][1]] = smallarray[w][y]
```

It does feel like there should be a better way or more efficient way. I looked through numpy's documentation to see if I could find something like this but I could not find it. Thoughts? Even if you think this is the best way any tips on improving my Python would be much appreciated.

Comment: You know the existence of slices, why do you need to assign values through iteration?

Comment: I think you basically want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690248/copy-numpy-array-into-part-of-another-array, except you need to also check whether the indices are out-of-bounds.

Comment: @MechanicPig Can you show what you mean (even just in pseudo code)? I think the hard part is the centering part, and I can't see how you match the  smallarrays values to the maparray without iterating through while knowing where you are trying to place each element.

Comment: @AdamOppenheimer It is close but I do not want an evenly padded array, the placement of where the values go is arbitrary, not directly in the center of the new array. I don't think padding works here.

Comment: @mf7aXtUs the first answer in the post I linked demonstrates array slicing

Comment: You two are right, I tried it with slicing. I don't quite see how to center it, but slicing is definitely the way to go. Thanks. (I am very new to programming so I honestly didnt really consider slicing)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given:

```
import numpy as np

maparray = np.zeros((9, 9))
smallarray = np.ones((3, 3)) * 2
```

We can simply assign to a slice:

```
# to assign with the top-left at (1, 2)
maparray[1:4, 2:5] = smallarray
```

which we can generalize:

```
def imprint(big, small, position):
    y, x = position
    h, w = small.shape
    big[y:y+h, x:x+w] = small
```

If we need to wrap around the outside, then we can take a different approach, still without needing any conditional logic. Simply roll the `big` array such that the "imprinting" location is at the top-left; assign the values; then roll back. Thus:

```
def imprint(big, small, position):
    y, x = position
    h, w = small.shape
    copy = np.roll(big, (-y, -x), (0, 1))
    copy[:h, :w] = small
    big[:, :] = np.roll(copy, (y, x), (0, 1))
```

Let's test it:

```
>>> imprint(maparray, smallarray, (7, 7))
>>> maparray
array([[2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.]])
>>> imprint(maparray, smallarray, (2, 2))
>>> maparray
array([[2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 2.]])
```

We see that we can correctly leave the results from previous imprints in place, and also wrap around the edge.

It also works with negative indices and large indices, wrapping around in the expected manner:

```
>>> maparray[:] = 0 # continuing from before
>>> imprint(maparray, smallarray, (-1, -1))
>>> maparray
array([[2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.]])
>>> # Keep in mind the first coordinate is for the first axis, which
>>> # displays vertically here (hence labelling it `y` in the code).
>>> imprint(maparray, smallarray, (40, 0))
>>> maparray
array([[2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2.]])
```

It will presumably be more efficient to use conditional logic explicitly (left as an exercise here), but this approach is elegant and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my adjustment to @Shahab Rahnama's solution that accounts for @Mechanic Pig's comment about the shift only working for (3x3) matrices, and my comment about the code not working if the matrix is placed with some elements out of bounds.

```py
import numpy as np

def imprint(center, bigarray, smallarray):
    half_height = smallarray.shape[0] // 2
    half_width = smallarray.shape[1] // 2
    top = center[0] - half_height
    bottom = center[0] + half_height + 1
    left = center[1] - half_width
    right = center[1] + half_width + 1
    bigarray[ \
        max(0, top): \
            min(bigarray.shape[0], bottom),
        max(0, left): \
            min(bigarray.shape[1], right)
    ] = smallarray[ \
            (top < 0) * abs(top): \
                smallarray.shape[0] - (bottom > bigarray.shape[0]) * (bottom - bigarray.shape[0]), \
            (left < 0) * abs(left): \
                smallarray.shape[1] - (right > bigarray.shape[1]) * (right - bigarray.shape[1]) \
    ]
    return bigarray

bigarray = np.zeros((7, 7))
smallarray = 2 * np.ones((5, 5))

imprint((3, 3), bigarray, smallarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create index arrays using np.meshgrid and the smallarray's shape.

```
bigarray = np.zeros((9, 9))
smallarray = np.zeros((3, 3)) + 2
x,y = smallarray.shape
xv,yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x),np.arange(y))
#print(xv)
#print(yv)
```

Those can be used on the *left-hand-side* of an assignment to *imprint* the smallarray. Without modification the smallarray will be positioned in the *upper-left* corner.

```
bigarray[xv,yv] = smallarray
print(bigarray)
```

---

```
[[2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The position can be changed by adding a scalar to the index arrays.

```
bigarray[xv+2,yv+3] = smallarray + 4
print(bigarray)
```

---

```
[[2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 2. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 2. 2. 6. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 6. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 6. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The scalars will be the index in the bigarray where the `[0,0]` point of the smallarray will be placed. If the function needs to accept the position of the center of the smallarray just use its shape to calculate the appropriate scalar. Also use both arrays' shape to calculate whether the small one will fit then adjust.

---

The index arrays can also be made with .indices.

```
xv,yv = np.indices(smallarray.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way :

```
import numpy as np

maparray = np.zeros((9, 9))
smallarray = np.zeros((3, 3))
smallarray[:] = 2


def imprint(center, maparray, smallarray):
    maparray[center[0]:center[0]+smallarray.shape[0],center[1]:center[1]+smallarray.shape[1]] = smallarray
    return maparray


print(imprint((3, 5), maparray, smallarray))
```

I used `roll` to overcome out-of-bounds (if the center is on the edge like [7,7] and [4,7], the `smallarray` will be out-of-bounds):

```
import numpy as np

maparray = np.zeros((9, 9))
smallarray = np.zeros((3, 3))
smallarray[:] = 2


def imprint(center, maparray, smallarray):
    rollx= 0
    rolly= 0
    if maparray.shape[0] - center[0] < smallarray.shape[0]:
        rollx = maparray.shape[0] - center[0] - smallarray.shape[0]
        center[0] = center[0] - abs(rollx )
    if maparray.shape[1] - center[1] < smallarray.shape[1]:
        rolly = maparray.shape[1] - center[1] - smallarray.shape[1]
        center[1] = center[1] - abs(rolly )
    
    maparray[center[0]:center[0]+smallarray.shape[0],center[1]:center[1]+smallarray.shape[1]] = smallarray
    return np.roll(maparray, (abs(rollx ), abs(rolly )), axis=(0, 1))


print(imprint([7, 7], maparray, smallarray))
```

Output:

```
[[2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]
 [2. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2.]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the small array is placed such that some of the elements will be out-of-bounds, which was stated as one of the conditions for the requested function.

Comment: The -1 here is rather lax, which is only valid for matrices with (3, 3) shape.

Comment: @AdamOppenheimer yes, you can check shapes in an if...else statement and split it to what you want.

Comment: @MechanicPig I don't take your point. I add it BCZ array starts from 0

Comment: Try `imprint((3, 3), np.zeros((7, 7)), np.ones((5, 5)))`, does it place 1 in the range of the middle (5,5) of the matrix? A simpler example is `imprint((1, 1), np.zeros((3, 3)), np.ones((1, 1)))`, which places 1 in the upper left corner of the matrix instead of the center.

Comment: @AdamOppenheimer I don't see where such a condition is stated.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Actually I think you are right, I misread "Ignoring indexing errors and even arrays that have no center." as meaning mf7aXtUs wanted to allow matrices to go out-of-bounds, and indexing could be ignored, but maybe he/she/they just meant don't worry about checking that the center is inside the array.

Comment: @AdamOppenheimer For my specific case I don't want wrapping, I planned on catching it with a Try except block. Wrapping would be incorrect for my case but it is nice that people included it in their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your requirement for "center" alignment<sup>1</sup>, let's say you want to place the values of some array `a1` into another array `a2` with some offset `offset`. `offset` is the coordinate in `a2` where `a1[0, 0, ..., 0]` ends up. The values can be negative without wrapping.

The sizes of the arrays are irrelevant. We only need to assume that the types are at least somewhat compatible, and that `a1.ndim == a2.ndim == len(offset)`. Let's call the number of dimensions `d`.

The goal is to be able to create a tuple of slices for each array, so that the assignment becomes a simple indexing operation:

```
a2[index2] = a1[index1]
```

So let's start writing this function:

```
def emplace(a1, a2, offset):
    offset = np.asanyarray(offset)
    if a1.ndim != a2.ndim or a1.ndim != len(offset) or len(offset) != offset.size:
        raise ValueError('All dimensions must match')
```

First let's filter out the cases where there is no overlap at all:

```
    if a1.size == 0 or a2.size == 0:
        return
    if (offset + a1.shape <= 0).any() or (offset >= a2.shape).any():
        return
```

Now that you know that there will be overlap, you can compute the starting indices for both arrays. If `offset` is negative, that truncates leading elements from `a1`. If it's positive, it skips elements in `a2`.

```
    start1 = np.where(offset < 0, -offset, 0)
    start2 = np.where(offset < 0, 0, -offset)
```

The ends can be computed in a similar manner, except that the bound check is done on the opposite end now:

```
    stop1 = np.where(offset + a1.shape > a2.shape, a2.shape - offset, a1.shape)
    stop2 = np.where(offset + a1.shape > a2.shape, a2.shape, offset + a1.shape)
```

You can construct tuples of indices from the bounds:

```
    index1 = tuple(slice(*bounds) for bounds in np.stack((start1, stop1), axis=-1))
    index2 = tuple(slice(*bounds) for bounds in np.stack((start2, stop2), axis=-1))
```

And so the final emplacement becomes just a simple assignment:

```
    a2[index2] = a1[index1]
```

**TL;DR**

Here is how I would write the full function:

```
def emplace(a1, a2, offset):
    offset = np.asanyarray(offset)

    if a1.ndim != a2.ndim or a1.ndim != len(offset) or len(offset) != offset.size:
        raise ValueError('All dimensions must match')

    if a1.size == 0 or a2.size == 0:
        return
    if (offset + a1.shape <= 0).any() or (offset >= a2.shape).any():
        return

    noffset = -offset
    omask = offset < 0
    start1 = np.where(omask, noffset, 0)
    start2 = np.where(omask, 0, noffset)

    omask = offset + a1.shape > a2.shape
    stop1 = np.where(omask, a2.shape - offset, a1.shape)
    stop2 = np.where(omask, a2.shape, offset + a1.shape)

    index1 = tuple(slice(*bounds) for bounds in np.stack((start1, stop1), axis=-1))
    index2 = tuple(slice(*bounds) for bounds in np.stack((start2, stop2), axis=-1))
    a2[index2] = a1[index1]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not suggesting you actually ignore how you want to do things. Just convert the center alignment to a corner offset.

Comment: Note: this function is pretty general and will work on arrays of any dimension. The bad part is that is written on mobile, completely untested, and I won't have the means to test it for at least a couple more days.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I believe the line     if (offset + a1.shape <= 0).any() or (offset >= a2.shape).any():
        return                                 is always going to return without doing the rest. (How the hell do I press enter without it auto posting?)